# Unexpected compilation error when using angular js ng-attr directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Below code I have used for adding ng-init attribute to a directive dynamically. The code is working fine and got the output as I expected but in runtime I am getting some compilation error.

*angular.js:13920 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{dashboardOptions.contentSettingsOptions.dynamicContent.enable && 'item=tileData[dashIndex].tiles[$index]' || '' }}]*

```
    <tile ng-attr-ng-init="{{dashboardOptions.contentSettingsOptions.dynamicContent.enable ?'item=tileData[dashIndex].tiles[$index]' : '' }}" 
                       dashboard-item="tile" 
                       ng-repeat="tile in dashitem.TileDefinitions track by $index"
                       >

            </tile>
```

**I am getting the expected output**

```
<tile ng-attr-ng-init="{{dashboardOptions.contentSettingsOptions.dynamicContent.enable ?'item=tileData[dashIndex].tiles[$index]' :'' }}" dashboard-item="tile" ng-repeat="tile in dashitem.TileDefinitions track by $index"  class="ng-scope angulardashboard-item tile" ng-init="item=tileData[dashIndex].tiles[$index]"></tile>
```

**Plunker**
https://plnkr.co/edit/9PBwouxYrzeKsEqtXbht?p=preview

How can I avoid this runtime error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve by using `ng-init` ?
`ng-attr` is for allowing angular to handle standard HTML attribute. A falsy value will make the attribute not showing up, a truthy value with make the attribute appear with the value.

Here you may want to do :

```
<div ng-init="item = canadd ? tileData[dashIndex].tiles[$index] : null">{{message}}</div>
```

Comment: I am adding ng-init attr dynamically based on some condition .I am getting the expected output but angularjs produce some compilation error in runtime along with the result.